# Angular FormArray of controls , how to get summary?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have FormGroup which has products formArray in it  (dynamic controls which can be added or removed) :

```
FormGroup {
  controls {
    products (FormArray) {
      0 : {summary.value: 5}...
      1 : {summary.value: 8}..
there can be N of these controls...
    }
  }
}
```

Expected summary = 5+8 = 13

I want to get all summary.value and summ them. How do I do that ?

What I've done but thats not working as expected :

```
   calculateAllSummary(formGroup: FormGroup) {
      Object.values(formGroup.controls.products['controls']).forEach((value: FormControl) => {

                let summaryControl: FormControl = value['controls'].summary;
                this.summarySubscription = summaryControl.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
                    if(this.checkIfValuesArentTheSame(val) == true){
                        let price = val;
                        if (price != null && typeof price == "string") {


                price = price.split(',').join('');
                    }
                    let numericValue = 0 + Number(price);
                    this.summaryValue = this.dp.transform(numericValue, '2.2-5');

                };
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            },
            );
    });
}
```

Problem with my function is that whenever I write summary in another product , it refreshes to anothers product summary number, but I want to add it to the last summary control value. I know that happens because of this line : let `numericValue = 0 + Number(price)`, but I can't figure out how to do it in another way.

Comment: Please provide additional information ok what you have tried already. The main goal of Stack Overflow is to help unblock people when they cannot progress in solving a problem. It’s not to provide solutions out of the box.

Comment: Adding my try to the question, check it.

Comment: I have an old stackblitz I made which seems to be along lines you are looking for - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-plp4rb-formarray-total-16z24o (please check before using)

Comment: I will try your example

Answer (score 1):

Reduce the entries of your object.

```js
const formValue = {
  summaryOne: '5',
  summaryTwo: '8',
  someRandomFieldToExclude: 'LOL'
};

const totalSummary = Object
  .entries(formValue)
  .filter(([key]) => key.toLowerCase().includes('summary'))
  .reduce((p, [, v]) => p += +v, 0);
  
console.log(totalSummary);
```